# Browser locks up streaming data from Azure IoT Hub

Tags: c#, azure, signalr, streaming

I'm streaming data from an Azure IoT Hub. The data is in Avro format, so I use an Avro reader and step through the data I get from my Event Hub Receiver. I then use SignalR to broadcast the data to a chart. I tried Kendo charts and Highcharts before noticing that Chrome seems to randomly lock up and the charts stop updating with new data (it's definitely a Chrome freezing issue because the Chrome console locks up when the charts do). Sometimes this happens immediately on run, and sometimes after a few seconds of the chart updating. I'm wondering if I'm broadcasting more data than Chrome can handle. 'Anyone with experience in this out there?

Comment: How much are you actually updating? At which speed? Can you test on IE/Edge/Firefox/Safari to rule out a Chrome bug?

Answer (score 0):

There was a delay somewhere in the Hub Receiver, I think. When I tried consuming the data a different way, the delay in getting data went away. I also decimated my data to give the browser a chance to keep up, and that helped.